# zipWithIndex and filter resulting in "Vector" string in output

Tags: scala, filter, zipwith

I am still struggling a bit with these zipWithIndex and filter functions. I have this code statement , and added a test string to isolate from the rest of the code.

```
val s = "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
val l = s.zipWithIndex.filter{tuple => tuple._2 % 4 == 0}.map{_._1}.toString()
```

I had expected to get a string with every 5th character from the original string, which does kind-of happen. Instead what I get is:

```
 Vector(0, 4, 8, 2, 6, 0, 4, 8, 2, 6, 0, 4, 8, 2, 6)
```

For some reason it seems to have spaces added, and also the word `Vector` in the string. Where does that come from? It is there without the `.toString()` (that was to change the type for later). And more to the point, how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

To join a sequence of characters, you can use [`mkString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html#mkString:String):

```
scala> Vector('1', '2').mkString
res0: String = "12"
```

in your case:

```
val l = s.zipWithIndex.filter{tuple => tuple._2 % 4 == 0}.map{_._1}.mkString
```

Here you're using [`.toString()`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html#toString():String) which is the usual method used to represent what an object is. In this case a Vector and its content:

```
scala> Vector('1', '2').toString
res1: String = "Vector(1, 2)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly join the members of the vectors, instead of calling `toString`. You can use [`mkString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html#mkString:String) for this. Here's a complete working example:

```
val s = "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
val l = s.zipWithIndex.filter{tuple => tuple._2 % 4 == 0}.map{_._1}.mkString
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668822/432903) to use `mkString("")` to concat `List` data-structures.

you might want to use `Range` instead of `zipWithIndex` and make only one traversal on string.

```
scala> val s = "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
s: String = 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

scala> (0 until s.length by 4).map(index => s(index)).mkString("")
res1: String = 048260482604826
```

Because underlying `java.lang.String` maintains an array which means `O(1)` for retrieval

```
private final char value[];

public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

*it is fp anyway so you might not care about space/time.*

Comment: Thanks, nicer solution than my original.

Comment: what error you get? The posted code definitely works and I run in my scala REPL.

Comment: I do not get an error as such, and as I said I do get the correct result. It is the Vector type that is the problem.